# Launch bash subshell and run commands in a script

Tags: bash, pipenv, mkdocs

I want to write a shell script that does the following:

1. Activate [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) virtual environment
2. Runs `mkdocs serve` which starts a local dev server for my [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) documentation

If I do the naïve thing and put this in my script:

```
cd <my-docs-directory>
pipenv shell
mkdocs serve
```

it fails because `pipenv shell` "launches a subshell in the virtual environment". I need to pass the `mkdocs serve` command into the virtual shell (and preferably land in that same shell after running the script ).

Thanks in advance!

## Answer

[Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125671/philippe)'s answer works. Here's why.

```
pipenv run bash -c 'mkdocs serve ; exec bash --norc'
```

1. Pipenv allows you to run a command in the virtual environment without launching a shell:

   ```
   $ pipenv run <insert command here>
   ```
2. `bash -c <insert command here>` allows you to pass a command to bash to execute

   ```
   $ bash -c "echo hello"
   hello
   ```
3. `exec` serves to replace current shell process with a command, so that parent goes a way and child owns pid. Here's a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525767/what-does-an-exec-command-do) on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command :

```
pipenv run bash -c 'mkdocs serve ; exec bash --norc'
```